# php- Apply formatting on specific HTML tags

Tags: php, html, tags

I am having an issue that I am rendering a text that was being entered in the DB using text editor. 
Now I have some conditions of basis of which I have to apply formatting on some specific tags like if there is a word 'teacher' in  a `<p>` or in `<h1>` or in `<h2>` it should be changed to 'student'.
I am not sure how to apply formatting on specific `html` tags

**EDIT**
Like I have the following text entered in the DB

```
<p>teacher</p>
<h1>parent</h1>
<h2>TEACHER</h2>
<h3>PARENT</h3>
<strong>parent</strong>
```

I want to replace the word **teacher** with **student** only if it is in `<p>` or in `<h1>` or in `<h2>`

Comment: CSS doesn't work for you? Or are you trying to replace certain words?

Comment: Question is unclear. Please give us a sample of what results you're getting as well as the results you want to achieve.

Comment: @JayBlanchard nops `css` doesn't work here. I am trying to replace the text withing certain tags

Comment: Use [a PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: css can't really change the contents of a dom node like that,you'll need something else, like php or javascript, to mangle the text for you.

Comment: @RichardTheobald please see the edit

Comment: @baig772 Ah, from the edit it is clear that you will need either to do string manipulation as the DOM is being created or some kind of DOM editing. You can do the latter with a PHP DOM parser or with javascript (I prefer javascript as it's more well known and thus easier to find answers to questions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use preg_replace:

```
$str = '<p>teacher is reading</p>
<h1>parent</h1>
<h2>TEACHER</h2>
<h3>PARENT</h3>
<strong>parent</strong>';

//for word in string too
//i for insensitive
$resp = preg_replace('/<(p|h1|h2)>(.*?)(teacher)(.*?)<\/(p|h1|h2)>/i','<$1>$2student$4<‌​/$5>',$str);

var_dump($resp);
```

response:

```
<p>student</p>
<h1>parent</h1>
<h2>student</h2>
<h3>PARENT</h3>
<strong>parent</strong>
```

I don't know but in the html code is setted this code `<&zwnj;&#8203;/$5>` and the result give `<??/(tag)>`

improved code(cleaned):
[from_gist](https://gist.github.com/mig1098/da479a9ecc8f9a6fe1d1)

Comment: It helped me a bit. Any way to change the case sensitive words as well? also if there is a line of a text and I have to change just one word in it?

Comment: quit the `i` like this `/<(p|h1|h2)>(teacher)<\/(p|h1|h2)>/`

Comment: any way to change one word in the text? Like "<p>teacher is reading</p>" to "<p>student is reading</p>" ??

Comment: try this: `preg_replace('/<(p|h1|h2)>(.*?)(teacher)(.*?)<\/(p|h1|h2)>/i','<$1>$2student$4</$5>',$str);` for example`<p>teacher dfsdf wertret</p>`

Comment: @baig772 is how you expected?

Comment: you are a life saver :D edit your answer and I will accept it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101931/discussion-between-baig772-and-miglio).

Answer (score 3):

So here is one way:

```
str_replace("<p>teacher</p>", "<p>student</p>", $yourText );
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php